# Send http request using octet/stream via node.js

Tags: node.js, http, stream, httprequest, octetstring

Currently my usecase is my `node.js` Server `Server A` needs to create a CSV file then send that CSV to another Server `Server B` which only accepts `application/octet-stream`.

Currently I'm manually CURLing the csv to upload it to Server B.

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/octet-stream" 
    -X PUT https://someexample.com/url/what/not 
    --upload-file newlyCreated.csv
```

But I need to automate the curl above and wanted to use `node.js` since Server A is built in `node.js`. My instincts leads me to use streams but I can't seem to make it work.

```
fs.createReadStream('/path/to/csv').pipe(httpRequestToServerB)
```

Then respond to client and send a JSON that it is successful

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I've found the answer to my question using `request` NPM module:

```
fs.createReadStream('/path/to/csv').pipe(request.post('url').on('end', (done) => {
  console.log('Upload Done')
}));
```

Hope this helps